# Mongodb E11000 Duplicate key error for non-existing document

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongoose, collation, mlab

**UPDATE**

Still having trouble, I've tried doing all of this in mongo shell and the error looks even weirder:

```
db.coupons.createIndex({ event: 1, code: 1 }, { unique: true, name: 'event_1_code_1_2', collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } })

{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: heroku_xxxxxx.coupons.$event_1_code_1_2 dup key: 
               { : ObjectId('5944128753af0c001feaaca6'), : \"-)COU)9O\u0001\f\" }",
    "code" : 11000,
    "codeName" : "DuplicateKey"
}
```

I promise, I've used `.find()` and searched manually for any document that even closely resembles this. I found NOTHING. This document doesn't exist, or mongodb has a weird hidden document feature that I don't know about.

---

I'm getting an error, and I understand what it means, but I can't find any document that would cause it.

I'm using heroku/mongoose/mlab and am trying to create a case-insensitive unique index:

```
CouponSchema.index({ event: 1, code: 1 }, { name: 'event_1_code_1_2', unique: true, collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } });
```

> Unhandled rejection MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index:
>   heroku_XXXXXX.coupons.$event_1_code_1_2 dup key: { :
>   ObjectId('59dfbf630dda30002665129b'), : "/9S9AES1" }

This isn't working on production (with existing data). Looking at the error I would think: **there is another document with code "/9S9AES1" that has differently cased characters**. But I search for ANY document with the code "/9S9AES1" and I find NOTHING.

I even have searched with:

```
"code": {
    "$regex": ".*9S9.*",
    "$options": "i"
}
```

and find no documents.

I also have a similar index without collation that works. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Have you tried searching for other documents with the same `event`?

Comment: Also, try searching without using $regex like so: `.find({code:"/9S9AES1"}).collation({locale: "en", strength: 2})`

Comment: No use. Still no documents. The uniqueness is only imposed on the compound of event and code, so same event is fine as long as it's not the same code.

Comment: Yes, of course but you might get a handful of documents back that you could inspect manually and you skip the collation topic once you query for an object Id. Otherwise my last guess is that you're not looking at the right server, database or collection.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion but I've actually looked through all documents and can't find any that even closely resemble one with the code: "/9S9AES1". I've got a cluster with a primary and secondary on mlab. Not sure if that matters. I only have one db.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "unique" property from Schema or do not use the same tab to signup with multiple accounts unless you sign out one of them from your current tab. After you removed unique property, delete all data from database and signup again. I hope it will help. It did mine